# Closing for off-topic, unreleased content per region?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

With the release of Pokemon Go being staggered, not all regions have yet received an official release for the game. Due to this, I am seeing three potential categories for users:

- Those who installed the game legitimately
- Those who installed the game off APK Mirror or similar sites
- Those who logged into a friend/colleague's account and downloaded the game

My question is related to the last two. Since the game has been released, questions regarding it are considered on topic.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275359/pokemon-go-no-nearby-in-busy-area) is what got me thinking about it, specifically the following portion:

> Is it because I haven't updated? Btw I can't update because I am Canadian and I downloaded using my American friends account.

Ostensibly this user should have updated to the latest version prior to attempting further troubleshooting attempts. Of course, that could be communicated as part of a well-detailed answer instead of simply closing the question.

Due to the complications associated with such a staggered release, should we be closing questions specifically pertaining to issues with games not released in a given region?

Comment: -> http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/pok%c3%a9mon-gotta-qatch-em-all

Comment: read the two upvoted answers.

Comment: Side note.. anyone in Canada can create a U.S. Apple ID and download the game and receive updates. I'm a U.S. citizen living in Canada so I already had one, so literally all I did was download the game. I can't speak for people who get cracked APKs on Android, but questions I ask shouldn't be closed because I'm physically in Canada.